# i want to change url in laravel project, how to remove public?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to upload my website project in my subfolder directory. my all project in laravel 5.8 so i cant able to do.
how to remove public.
-when I want run some pages must write public in my subfolder that's the problem.

so please help me, anyone,

Comment: You can't just upload Laravel to a web server. You need to install database and import composer dependencies, among a few other steps.

Comment: Change the document root of your server accordingly, hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184358/setting-document-root-for-laravel-project-on-apache-virtual-host

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574810/can-i-install-a-laravel-project-in-a-subdirectory-of-my-server

Comment: Hi you want to remove public folder in our laravel project ?
like baseurl/public to baseurl
?

Comment: You can add RewriteBase /project/public in your .htaccess